# Diffrence between directly clicking on element vs Click on element by Action Class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just want to know is there any diffrence between clicking on webelement by Action class or directly clicking on it.

Let say we have an button1 on web page then

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);  
 action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("button1")));
 action.Click().Build().Perform();

               VS  
driver.FindElement(By.Id("button1").Click();
```

What is the diffrence between above two statments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading the [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)?

The [Actions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html?topic=html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) class:

> The user-facing API for emulating complex user gestures. Use this class rather than using the Keyboard or Mouse directly.

Specifically the [click](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html?topic=html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_Click.htm) method:

> Clicks at the current mouse location.

Whereas the [WebDriver.click](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html?topic=html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Click.htm) method:

> Click this element. If this causes a new page to load, this method will attempt to block until the page has loaded.